# Former French PM Blum was in Buchenwald -- what is known about his life there?

Tags: france, holocaust, nazism

To me it is interesting that he received special treatment rather than immediate execution. He was considered extremely valuable perhaps as a hostage. Wondering any details about how and why he was treated differently than most other inmates there.

[Wikipedia article mentioning special section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9on_Blum)  Mind-boggling that such a man was not exempt from Nazi imprisonment; on the other hand, in his own land he was dragged from his automobile and almost beaten to death, saved by members of the proletariat who were fortunately nearby. (ibid)

Comment: I can remove "assume" -- former French PM is extremely valuable as a hostage without doubt. Wikipedia article mentions his being assigned to special section of Buchenwald which it is known resulted in better treatment than regular inmates.

Answer (score 7):

In fact, the Nazis kept a group of captured important political leaders in a special subcamp of Buchenwald, as sort of hostages, under *relatively* mild conditions.

For some reason I am unable now to find a single source with a full list of the VIP prisoners (I recall once having read such a webpage). Anyway, the subcamp was called "Fichtenhain Special Camp" and this [google book](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=d7WlV23kNoUC&pg=PA195&lpg=PA195&dq=Fichtenhain%20Special%20Camp&source=bl&ots=PKVB-Ie2De&sig=Qgf7Rs8rO1Yo_JenVM68sQ_BpaI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjpr6Hs-NXPAhVBWhoKHap4AwQQ6AEIITAB#v=onepage&q=Fichtenhain%20Special%20Camp&f=false) has some valuable information on it.

[This webpage](http://warfarehistorynetwork.com/daily/wwii/wwii-concentration-camps-the-horrific-discovery-at-buchenwald/) is also useful. Here's the most relevant section:

> [Princess Mafalda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princess_Mafalda_of_Savoy) was not the only politically important prisoner at
>   Buchenwald. An area known as the Fichtenhain Special Camp and its
>   adjacent isolation barrack located between the SS barracks and the
>   Gustloff-Werk II also held a variety of men, women, and children who
>   were not allowed to mingle with the general concentration camp
>   population.
>
> French politicians, especially, were “guests” of the Nazis at
>   Buchenwald. Léon Blum, a Jew and the former premier of the French
>   Popular Front government from 1936 to 1938, was imprisoned here after
>   the French Free Zone was occupied by the Germans in November 1942,
>   following the Allied invasion of North Africa. Other members of the
>   French government held at KL Buchenwald included Édouard Daladier
>   (prime minister in 1940); Georges Mandel (the last minister of the
>   interior before the fall of France in 1940); and General Maurice
>   Gamelin (commander in chief of French and British forces in 1940).
>   Also incarcerated atop the Etterberg were Reserve Division General
>   Andre Challe and his son; Professor Alfred Balachowsky, director of
>   the Pasteur Institute; and a Mssr. Clin, director of the National
>   Library of France.
>
> Here also was kept Dr. Rudolph Breitscheid, former chairman of the
>   German Social Democrat Party, and his wife. In the cellar of one of
>   the SS troop barracks was a special row of cells known as the SS
>   detention area, where the Protestant theologian Dietrich Bonhoeffer
>   was kept. Later evacuated to Flossenbürg, Bonhoeffer was hanged on
>   April 9, 1945, just days before the camp was liberated.
>
> KL Buchenwald did not discriminate when it came to the nationalities
>   of its prisoners. Buchenwald also held as inmates Anton Falkenberg,
>   head of the Copenhagen police; [Petr Zenkl, the former mayor of Prague](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petr_Zenkl);
>   British Wing Commander Forest Yeo-Thomas; and a former prime minister
>   of Belgium, Paul-Emile Janson, who died at Buchenwald in 1944.

Comment: I did read that towards the end, the decision to murder Blum was made but not carried out. But it could well have happened -- Mandel was murdered and so was Blum's brother. I am sure the relatively mild conditions were nonetheless not quite like living at the Ritz.

Comment: @Jeff Not at all like the Ritz. Still, better than what was being done to the "regular" prisoners in Buchenwald.